# Matlab 'Open Outside MATLAB' uses Internet Explorer for XML

Tags: windows, matlab, internet-explorer

The Matlab 'Open Outside MATLAB' uses Internet Explorer for XML even if the associated Application is set to something else in Windows. Does anybody know a way/hack/script to fix this?

Comment: It should open the file with the application you associated in Windows, did you restart Matlab after changing the settings?

Comment: Yes, it works for every extension except XML. If I double-click on an XML in the regular Explorer, it works as well...just not within Matlab.